# How to get Gmail "forget password" link using Cypress

Tags: authentication, gmail, cypress

I am able to check Gmail is sent to the user, but I want to get forget password link from the received email and visit it using cypress-Gmail-tester. I am working on an ongoing project and whenever a gmail-tester is implemented it will work as per the below code.

```javascript
it('forget password', () => {
    const startStr = 'x3IhzZ5YUFU3xRWkCJI4aLVPC-2BOoHahfDU-2BROGlySass0TTVgllosmDa-2FaVEbjjZN-2FuCMhKKtmBUzbdxwO9z-2F'
    const endStr = '-3D'
    cy.visit('https://app.dev.##########.co/');
    cy.get('.login__forgotpass').click();
    cy.get('.forgot-pass__input').clear();
    cy.get('.forgot-pass__input').type('##########testhub+2@gmail.com')
    cy.get('.forgot-pass__btn').click();
    cy.get('.popUp__note').contains('Check');
    cy.get('.notification-dismiss').click();
    cy.task("gmail:get-messages", {
      options: {
        from: "info@########.co",
        subject: "Reset your ######## account password",
        include_body: true,
        // before: new Date(2021, 9, 24, 12, 31, 13), // Before September 24rd, 2019 12:31:13
        //  after: new Date(2021, 7, 23) // After August 23, 2019
      }
    }).then(emails => {
      assert.isAtLeast(
        emails.length,
        1,
        "Expected to find at least one email, but none were found!"
      );

      const body = emails[0].body.html;

      assert.isTrue(
        body.indexOf(

          "http://url3042.########.co/ls/click?upn=x3IhzZ5YUFU3xRWkCJI4aLVPC-2BOoHahfDU-2BROGlySass0TTVgllosmDa-2FaVEbjjZN-2FuCMhKKtmBUzbdxwO9z-2F"

        ) >= 0,
        "Found reset link!"
      );

      var token = extractData(body, startStr, endStr);
      cy.log(`http://url3042.#########.co/ls/click?upn=${token}-3D`)
      cy.visit(`http://url3042.#########.co/ls/click?upn=${token}-3D`)
    })
```

I have replaced `##########` to my project name because of some `NDA`.

Now I have written the below code but it will show `invalid token` when entering a new password and clicking on the button.

That means token it received from email.

```javascript
cy.task("gmail:get-messages", {
    options: {
      from: "noreply@######.co",
      subject: "Reset your ########## account password",
      include_body: true,
    }
  }).then(emails => {
    assert.isAtLeast(
      emails.length,
      1,
      "Expected to find at least one email, but none were found!"
    );

    const body = emails[0].body.html;

    assert.isTrue(
      body.indexOf(

        "token="

      ) >= 0,
      "Found reset link!"
    );

    var token = extractData(body, startStr, endStr);

    cy.log(`accept/reset-password?token=${token}-3D`)

    cy.visit(`accept/reset-password?token=${token}-3D`)
    cy.get(smokeTestPageSelector.signUpPassword).type(Cypress.env('password'))
    cy.get(smokeTestPageSelector.confirmPasswordTextbox).type(Cypress.env('password'))
    cy.get('.forgot-pass__btn').click()
    cy.get(hubGroupPageSelector.popupNotes).should('have.text','Password successfully reset!')
```

But now it will not work because of many changes made to the project. I want to check my email and get the received link and then visit that link.

Comment: If gmail-tester returns the html of the email, you could write that to the current document. Also, what point is your failure at with your code?

Comment: how to write that can you please let me know

Comment: @jjhelguero I have updated my question with what I have currently written.

Comment: If gmail-tester returns html then you can do `cy.document({ log: false }).invoke({ log: false }, 'write', html)` as shown here in the [cypress-ethereal-email-example](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-ethereal-email-example/blob/d5ba3e174700ec8631e7d1a239f8773fcc60b51e/cypress/integration/check-email.js#L45).